# Upload file to .net core 3.1 API - ony half file received

Tags: file, .net-core, upload

I have a .net core 3.1 API controller that receives files for storage in Azure. But all files received are only "partly received" - for example if an image file is send to the controller - only half (or less) of the image is received.

I have the following controller definition:

```
[HttpPost()]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromQuery] Guid documentId)
 {
        HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();

        var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Request.ContentLength)];
        using (var stream = HttpContext.Request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
        {
                MemoryStream myStreamstream = new MemoryStream(buffer);

                myStreamstream.Position = 0;
                azureStorageHelper myStorageHelper = new azureStorageHelper();
                //helper method to get a writable BlockBlob (helper method works in other projects)
                Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = 
                myStorageHelper.getWriteableFileBlobFromAzure("test" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".jpg");

                await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(myStreamstream).ContinueWith(
                (copyTask) =>
                {
                });
        }
}
```

File is uploaded with PostMan (for testing) as "binary/Select file"

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBqiy.png)

[Image saved by the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbjBW.png)

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem.
It seems that the BlobStorage SDK only uploads the buffered part of the stream and ignores the rest!
Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: No I still havn't found a solution.

Comment: What i ended up doing is the following
1) remove HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
2) store the file into Azure
3) read the file from blobstorage then take the necessary action.